TV movie: Mother regains custody of children
A late 1980’s/early 1990’s U.S. made-for-TV movie drama in the same vein as “Desperate Rescue: The Cathy Mahone Story” (1993, TV, Mariel Hemingway, Clancy Brown, Jeff Kober), and “Reckoning” (1996, TV, Lorraine Bracco, Lisa Jakub).  
A father takes his son and daughter (ages 6 – 9 or so) away from their mother after a contentious divorce.  The mother hires two detectives/investigators to find her children who have been taken (I believe) to another state.  
Her plan is to retake them.  Toward the end of the movie, the mother and two detectives (both male, if I remember) wait in a van outside the elementary school the two children are attending. School lets out and the mother sees her children, and one detective says, “It’s now or never” and the mother exclaims, “I want them!” and the two children are picked up and taken into the van for a speedy get-away.  
The mother may have been played by Meredith Baxter or Joanna Kerns, but their filmographies don’t confirm this.  
Aired in primetime on ABC/CBS/NBC and may have rerun on Lifetime or True Movies.  Keywords “abduction,” “kidnapping,” and “child custody” don’t seem to be turning this up.  T
